# Execute .js immediately after particular <div> has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$(window).load(function ())` works very reliably, but you have to wait till all the page has been loaded to see the change on the div ( although it's at the top of the page).

Simply putting code after div doesn't work after refresh and the same with .ready function.

Example: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ye8NN/14/)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve in the fiddle?

Comment: i dont think you can get the height of a `<div>` before it's loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can use jQuery's `load` method on an element like `<div>` because it doesn't fire a load event. But images do:

Perhaps wrap it in jQuery's `ready` method:

```
$(window).ready(function(){

  $('div img').load(function(){

    // code to run after div's image has loaded

  });
})
```

**EDIT**:

In response to your fiddle, if you're wanting to run JavaScript before the `<p>` then you can just put the `<script>` before it in the document. JavaScript gets run as it is encountered by the browser, so this should work:

```
<div id="texture">
  <!-- All your spans -->
</div>
<script>
  alert('this will run before your p element is loaded');
</script>
<p>I would prefer to run script before this text is loaded</p>
```

Comment: sorry, I tried this way, but the code don't work at all in this case

Comment: What are you waiting to load within the div?

Comment: I added js fiddle demo in the question

Comment: sorry it doesn't work -  seems like my script in real life works well only with $(window).load(function ())

Comment: btw you mean <script> instead of <style> in your edited response?

Comment: @Robert002 Yes, that was a typo. But this will definitely work. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNJkh/) proves it. As you can see, the `alert` message comes before the `<p>` text is loaded. Make sure you're not putting your jQuery `load`/`ready` methods in it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use css to hide the text and show it using jQuery after jQuery has initialized.